# how to get the x position of element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to Find the X of div in animation process by transformX,
when click on the page.
by javascript code without Jquery.
(x in pixels).
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the position of any element, including transformations like `translateX`, using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

```
const el = document.getElementById('my-element');
console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect().x); // The element's X position
```

[Element.getBoundingClientRect() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Luke Taylor,Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answer of Luke Taylor.

Check it out in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect